# Which function I am required to alter the table (add column) in a stored procedure? Select into? or Insert into?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on a complex stored procedure that is already existing. I wanted to add few more columns when I noticed that I need to alter the table / temptable first before I could add it in the stored procedure.

I thought the temp table is just temporary for that session , why do I have to alter the table before I could add a new column?

```
SELECT *INTO #FAC_CEDED_PREMIUM_Casualty_BA FROM
(
    SELECT 
        POLICY_NO AS POLICY_NO,
        REINSURANCE_CONTRACT AS REINSURANCE_CONTRACT_ID,
        EXTERNAL_CARRIER AS EXTERNAL_CARRIER_ID,
        INTERMEDIARY_CD AS INTERMEDIARY_CD,
        TRANS_ACCTG_TMONTHNUMBER AS ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,
        RC1.FAC_Certificate_NO as Certificate_No,
        RC1.COVERS_FULL_POLICY_IND AS COVERS_FULL_POLICY_IND,
        RC1.reinsurance_contract_type_cd as REINSURANCE_CONTRACT_TYPE_CD,
        RC.REINSURANCE_CONTRACT_REFERENCE_NO as REINSURANCE_CONTRACT_REFERENCE_NO,
        RC1.CONTRACT_CURRENCY as CONTRACT_CURRENCY,
        RC1.TREATY_OR_FACULTATIVE_CD,
        RC1.Contract_Nm,
        RC1.CONTRACT_EXPIRATION_DT,
        SUM(WRITTEN_PREMIUM_TRANSACTIONAL_CURRENCY_AMT) AS WRITTEN_PREMIUM,
        SUM(COMMISSION_TRANSACTIONAL_CURRENCY_AMT) AS COMMISSION 

    FROM CEDED_PREMIUM_Casualty_BA CP 
        INNER JOIN DW.VDWH_REINSURANCE_CONTRACT RC ON CP.REINSURANCE_CONTRACT = RC.ID
        INNER JOIN DW.VDWH_REINSURANCE_CONTRACT01 RC1 ON RC.ID = RC1.ID AND RC1.TO_DATE = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'
    WHERE 1=1

    GROUP BY POLICY_NO,RC1.TREATY_OR_FACULTATIVE_CD,REINSURANCE_CONTRACT,EXTERNAL_CARRIER,INTERMEDIARY_CD,
            FAC_CERTIFICATE_NO,
            Contract_Nm,
            RC1.CONTRACT_EXPIRATION_DT,
            TRANS_ACCTG_TMONTHNUMBER,
            COVERS_FULL_POLICY_IND,reinsurance_contract_type_cd,REINSURANCE_CONTRACT_REFERENCE_NO,CONTRACT_CURRENCY

)A

SELECT *INTO #FAC_FACT_LIMIT_Casualty_BA FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        VL.POLICY_NO,
        VL.REINSURANCE_CONTRACT_REFERENCE_NO,
        VL.REINSURANCE_CONTRACT,
        VL01.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_LIMIT_AMT ,
        VL01.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_PART_OF_AMT,
        VL01.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_EXCESS_OF_AMT,
        VL01.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_AGGREGATE_AMT,
        VL01.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_MINIMUM_AMT   ,
        VL01.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_MAXIMUM_AMT   ,
        VL01.FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY_LIMIT_AMT,
        VL01.FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY_PART_OF_AMT    ,
        VL01.FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY_EXCESS_OF_AMT  ,
        VL01.FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY_AGGREGATE_AMT,
        VL01.FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY_MINIMUM_AMT,   
        VL01.FUNCTIONAL_CURRENCY_MAXIMUM_AMT    
    FROM DW.VDWH_LIMIT VL 
   INNER JOIN DW.VDWH_LIMIT01 VL01 ON VL.ID = VL01.ID AND VL01.TO_DATE = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'
    WHERE 1=1--POLICY_NO  = '32ESP1546200'
    AND DIRECT_ASSUMED_CEDED_CD  = 'C'
)A 


**ALTER TABLE #FAC_CEDED_PREMIUM_Casualty_BA ADD FAC_LAYER_ID INT NULL**
```

Another set of Altering the table is this.

```
SELECT
    POLICY_NO,
    0 FAC_LAYER_ID,
    [Insured Name],
    [Effective Date],
    [Expiration Date],

    /* LS(093014) - Added Region and Underwriter */
    Region,
    Underwriter,
    /*********************************************/ 

    /* LS(101614) - Added BU and SubU            */
    Business_Division,
    Business_Subdivision,
    /*********************************************/

    REINSURANCE_CONTRACT_TYPE_CD,
    FAC_CERTIFICATE_NO,
    COVERS_FULL_POLICY_IND,
    CARRIER_NM,
    POLICY_STATUS_CD,

    GWP,
    COMMISION,
    CommisionPct,
    TotalCWP,
    NWP,
    'Treaty' TreatyFac,
    TreatyCededPremium CededPremium,
    TreatyCededCommission CededCommision,
    CAST(CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(TreatyCededPremium,0) <> 0 THEN ROUND((TreatyCededCommission/TreatyCededPremium) * 100,2)
        ELSE 0
    END AS DECIMAL(25,2)) CommissionPct,
    'QS' CedingType,--CHANGE IT LATER NOT HARDCODED
    1 Sort

INTO #TEMP_Reinsurance_Report_Details_Casualty_BA
FROM ERG.Reinsurance_Report_Summary_Casualty_BA WITH(NOLOCK) 

ALTER TABLE #TEMP_Reinsurance_Report_Details_Casualty_BA ADD 
    --FACLimit DECIMAL(18,2) NULL, 
    --FACAttachmentPoint DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
    --Reinsurer VARCHAR(500) NULL,
    --ReinsurerCWP DECIMAL(18,2) NULL, 
    --ReinsurerCommission DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
    --ReinsurerCommissionPCT DECIMAL(5,2) NULL


    **FACLimit DECIMAL(25,2) NULL, 
    FACAttachmentPoint DECIMAL(25,2) NULL,
    Reinsurer VARCHAR(500) NULL,
    ReinsurerCWP DECIMAL(25,2) NULL, 
    ReinsurerCommission DECIMAL(25,2) NULL,
    ReinsurerCommissionPCT DECIMAL(25,2) NULL**
```

Comment: As posted this doesn't make a lot of sense. The only question I see is asking about why you have to alter the table. That is because it is how you add columns to a table. It doesn't matter if it is a persistent table or a temp table. Once it is created, to change it you have to issue an alter statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to alter the table, you can just add the columns to the original select with null value + convert, like this:

```
SELECT 
    POLICY_NO AS POLICY_NO,
    ...
    convert(int, NULL) as FAC_LAYER_ID
```

Altering the temporary tables is usually not a good idea because it will prevent caching of the tables in temp db for the next run. You can read more details about this in Paul White's [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422150925/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/17/temporary-object-caching-explained.aspx)